# Do mathematicians ever prove that something can or can't be proved?

Tags: provability

I was just idly thinking about things people have a hard time proving, like P=NP, etc, and wondering if instead it could be proved that it's provable or unprovable.

Is that a thing? Does that ever happen?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're providing this as an example of someone proving that something can't be proved, right?

Comment: Yes. This is a counter-example to the Entscheidungsproblem.

Comment: Look up the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: Gödels incompleteness theorem states that in fact the vast majority of true facts can't be proven!

Comment: @Chanler : $\:$ What version of that says anything about the density of $\hspace{2.06 in}$ provable true facts vs. unprovable true facts? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Axiom of choice or Zorn;s lemma.

Comment: An example is Gauss, who proved that the Euclid's 5th axiom cannot be proved using the other 4 using hyperbolic geometry, a model for geometry where the first 4 axioms hol but not the 5th. This is an example where the constructs were thoroughly geometric, so not a logic/set theory example.

Comment: If you prove something to be provable, won't you just be proving it?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: My thought exactly! Constructivists might disagree (I am open to correction on this), but mainstream mathematics would accept such a proof.

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal Intuitionists (e.g. Brouwer) don't agree that they have proved something just by showing it's provable. They don't believe in proofs without explicit construction (e.g., proof by contradiction).

Comment: @BalarkaSen An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is something mathematicians sometimes do, particularly set theorists and logicians. There is, of course, Goedel's result that no theory can prove its own consistency. There are also results that exploit this to make other provability statements. An example from my own field is that New Foundations set theory can't prove that something called the Axiom of Counting, because if it did it would prove the consistency of NF; we conclude that it is either inconsistent with NF, or a proper strengthening of the theory. Similarly, independence results are exactly theorems stating that neither a statement nor its negation can be proven from a set of axioms.

Strangely, I can't think of any examples of proving that something is provable that don't actually involve proving it, though in principle there's no reason that couldn't happen.

Comment: About your last remark; I think that proving that something is provable requires one to show the existence of a proof. That in itself constitutes a proof of that something.

Comment: @Servaes: I meant a proof in the object language. I may be able to show in our meta-theory that something holds of all groups (or whatever) and that this something is a first order property without ever writing a proof in the language $\mathcal{L}=\{e,-^{-1},\cdot\}$.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example.  In the theory of groups, the proposition
$$
\forall x\;\forall y\quad xy=yx
$$
cannot be proved.  The way to show this is to exhibit a nonabelian group.

In fact, when we say "can be proved" or "cannot be proved" we mean **in a certain theory**.  And it makes no sense to say it without somehow having that theory in mind.